# query string returning controller name and method name in CI in Nginx server

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, query-string

I recently moved from Apache server to nginx server. The code is developed in CI. But the $_SERVER['query_string'] variable and $_GET variables showing controller name and method name as well. For eg. Suppose my url is:

http://jawed.com/coding/php/?utm_source=DRGFTB&utm_campaign=CODPAGT

Then the $_SERVER['query_string'] will have $_SERVER['query_string'] => '/coding/php/&utm_source=DRGFTB&utm_campaign=CODPAGT'. And if I print the $_GET variable it will show

Array ( [/coding/php/] => [utm_source] => DRGFTB [utm_campaign] => CODPAGT )

However it should not fetch controller/methodName. Even in Apache server I am not getting controller/methodName as a part of query string.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name jawed.com;
root /var/www/html/jawed/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
access_log /var/log/nginx/jawed-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/jawed-error.log;

location ~* \.(htaccess|htpasswd|log|sh|inc|bak|epub) {
    deny all;
    }
location ~ /\.svn {
    deny all;
}
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }
}
location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/jawed$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Jawed

Comment: What do you set QUERY_STRING to in `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`?

Comment: fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;

Comment: fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect